# Mixed outputs in VTK

Tags: python, vtk

I need to output 2-D data and 3-D data to the user simultaneously.  My preference would be to have both outputs available in the same window, but other suggestions are appreciated, as long as the result is simultaneous.

To plot 2d data I have used the following example...
http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Python/Plotting/ScatterPlot

To create a 3d plot, I have used 
renderer = vtk.vtkRenderer()
renderer.AddActor(pointCloud.vtkActor)

to start the process.

Hoping to combine the two into one window, I tried to modify this...
http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Python/MultipleViewports.

But I receive the following error..
TypeError: AddRenderer argument 1: method requires a vtkRenderer, a vtkContextView was provided.

Is there a way to create a 2d chart that can be added to a VTK window that also contains a 3d rendering?

Comment: Maybe it is a bit late now, despite vtkContextView has a renderer, it cannot be used directly like that. I think your best bet would be to use wxpython and use a class called wxVTKRenderWindowInteractor for each one of the plots, and keep them in separate windows, it is better

Comment: This was very helpful.  I ended up using the vtkContextView.GetRenderer() which as you say is indirect, but did work.  I started off in multiple windows, and that was too slow for the use.  With everything in one window the rendering time is greatly reduced.